# Problem with date loading in Spring App deployed to Heroku

Tags: java, spring, heroku

I have a simple spring boot application using postgres as a database. When I run the application locally everything is fine, but when I deploy it to heroku I get a NullPointerException when accessing the date property of the User object. When the bean is initialized, a User is created, the payment field initiated with new date, then the user is saved to the database, if after that the user is retrieved from the database, the date is null. When I run the application on local postgres everything is fine, the date is saved and after reloading the user it is present. What might be causing this error?

Here's User class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "current_fund")
    private int currentFund;

    @Column(name = "payment")    
    private Date payment;
```

And here's how User is created in userService:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    public UserService() {

    }

    public void save(User user) {
        userRepo.save(user);
    }

    public User getUser() {
        System.err.println("===============================");
        System.err.println("=IN USER SERVICE NOW=");
        System.err.println("===============================");
        User user = new User();
        user.setCurrentFund(0);
        user.setLogin("1");
        user.setPassword("2");
        user.setName("45");        
        user.setPayment(new Date());
        System.err.println("===============================");
        System.err.println("=USER CREATED=" + user.toString());
        System.err.println("===============================");
        userRepo.save(user);
        System.err.println("===============================");
        System.err.println("=USER SAVED=");
        System.err.println("===============================");
        User us = userRepo.findAll().iterator().next();
        System.err.println("===============================");
        System.err.println("=USER LOADED=" + us);
        System.err.println("===============================");
        return us;
    }
}
```

Here's Heroku logs tail:

```
2021-10-15T09:26:51.323443+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-15 09:26:51.323  INFO 4 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-10-15T09:26:51.326054+00:00 app[web.1]: ===============================
2021-10-15T09:26:51.326080+00:00 app[web.1]: =IN EVENT SERVICE INIT=
2021-10-15T09:26:51.326107+00:00 app[web.1]: ===============================
2021-10-15T09:26:51.326144+00:00 app[web.1]: ===============================
2021-10-15T09:26:51.326170+00:00 app[web.1]: =IN USER SERVICE NOW=
2021-10-15T09:26:51.326195+00:00 app[web.1]: ===============================
2021-10-15T09:26:51.326426+00:00 app[web.1]: ===============================
2021-10-15T09:26:51.326701+00:00 app[web.1]: =USER CREATED=User{id=0, name='45', login='1', password='2', currentFund=0, lastPaymentDate=Wed Sep 15 09:26:51 UTC 2021}
2021-10-15T09:26:51.326730+00:00 app[web.1]: ===============================
2021-10-15T09:26:52.018035+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-15 09:26:52.017  INFO 4 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.21.Final
2021-10-15T09:26:52.170196+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-15 09:26:52.170  INFO 4 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2021-10-15T09:26:52.994040+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-15 09:26:52.993  INFO 4 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
2021-10-15T09:26:54.444953+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-15 09:26:54.444  INFO 4 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-10-15T09:26:54.455185+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-15 09:26:54.454  INFO 4 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-10-15T09:26:55.163731+00:00 app[web.1]: ===============================
2021-10-15T09:26:55.163755+00:00 app[web.1]: =USER SAVED=
2021-10-15T09:26:55.163777+00:00 app[web.1]: ===============================
2021-10-15T09:26:55.355926+00:00 app[web.1]: ===============================
2021-10-15T09:26:55.355965+00:00 app[web.1]: =USER LOADED=User{id=1, name='45', login='1', password='2', currentFund=0, lastPaymentDate=null}
2021-10-15T09:26:55.355999+00:00 app[web.1]: ===============================
2021-10-15T09:26:55.356028+00:00 app[web.1]: ===============================
2021-10-15T09:26:55.356079+00:00 app[web.1]: =USER=User{id=1, name='45', login='1', password='2', currentFund=0, lastPaymentDate=null}
2021-10-15T09:26:55.356107+00:00 app[web.1]: ===============================
2021-10-15T09:26:55.402277+00:00 app[web.1]: start events update
2021-10-15T09:26:55.408357+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-15 09:26:55.408  WARN 4 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'purchaseController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eventsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventsService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
2021-10-15T09:26:55.408900+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-15 09:26:55.408  INFO 4 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-10-15T09:26:55.410937+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-15 09:26:55.410  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-10-15T09:26:55.411578+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-15 09:26:55.411  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-10-15T09:26:55.967177+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-15 09:26:55.966  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-10-15T09:26:55.969102+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-15 09:26:55.968  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.978337+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-15 09:26:55.978  INFO 4 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
2021-10-15T09:26:55.978338+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-10-15T09:26:55.978339+00:00 app[web.1]: Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982750+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-10-15 09:26:55.982 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982754+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982761+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'purchaseController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eventsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventsService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982762+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982762+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982764+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982765+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982765+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982765+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982766+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982766+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982767+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982767+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982767+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982768+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982768+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982768+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982769+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982769+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982770+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982770+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982770+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982771+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982771+00:00 app[web.1]: at main.Main.main(Main.java:9) [classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982772+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_302-heroku]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982772+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_302-heroku]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982776+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_302-heroku]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982777+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_302-heroku]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982777+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [purchase-planner-web2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982777+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107) [purchase-planner-web2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982778+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [purchase-planner-web2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982778+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) [purchase-planner-web2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982779+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventsService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982779+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982779+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:415) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982780+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982780+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982780+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982781+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982781+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982781+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982781+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982782+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982782+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982782+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982783+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982783+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 28 common frames omitted
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982784+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982784+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1770) ~[na:1.8.0_302-heroku]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982785+00:00 app[web.1]: at main.handlers.EventsService.getDate0AM(EventsService.java:246) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982785+00:00 app[web.1]: at main.handlers.EventsService.fillWithEmptyPayments(EventsService.java:72) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982785+00:00 app[web.1]: at main.handlers.EventsService.updateEvents(EventsService.java:49) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982786+00:00 app[web.1]: at main.handlers.EventsService.init(EventsService.java:42) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982786+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_302-heroku]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982787+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_302-heroku]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982789+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_302-heroku]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982790+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_302-heroku]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982791+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982791+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982791+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982792+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 40 common frames omitted
2021-10-15T09:26:55.982792+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-10-15T09:26:56.147680+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

When comment out all references to "payment" field, app starts just fine.
Also, there are other objects in my app, using Date as one of their fields, and these objects are loaded properly

Comment: `Error creating bean with name 'purchaseController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eventsService'; ` how about this? could you check your `purchaseController`?

Comment: @DilermandoLima eventsService has PostConstruct method in which user date field is called, so this error has the same cause of NPE

Comment: You error is point out to Bean **eventService** is null in **purchaseController** . I think you could post this part of code for better helping as  your log error has described